# Delete particular content from excel sheet with selected cells

Tags: excel, cell, selectedvalue, removeall

I have stuck with one task as I need to delete particular content like "6" from selected cells which is given below screenshot as example for excel sheet .

[image]

Comment: As an idea: you can try copy the content of your cells, insert into a separate table with splitting by separator so that your redundant value goes to a separate column, then remove the whole column with that value and merge contents back into one cell per row. I will still need to figure out how to make those steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula below in column O:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(N71,MID(N71,FIND(6, N71),3),"")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response!! I will get back to you shortly if it works.